# jQuery - Assign keys and values from an array

Tags: jquery

I'm currently looping around a series of checkboxes that have a specific name assigned to them. Whatever checkbox is checked it gets the value and puts it in an array.

```
var filterHeight = $('input[name="filter-height"]:checked');
var userArray = [];    

filterHeight.each(function(){
    userArray.push($(this).val());      
});
```

So the output could be something like **short, medium, tall**

How would I assign a key value to the array values? I'm looking to do something like:

```
$(document).trigger('showHeight', {
    short: true,
    medium: false,
    tall: false
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `userArray[$(this).val()] = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an object so try:

```
var filterHeight = $('input[name="filter-height"]');
var userObj = {}; 
filterHeight.each(function () {
    userObj[this.value] = this.checked;
});


$(document).trigger('showHeight', userObj);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2eNJ/)**